# How to find if datetime is lesser than 24 hours in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Lets say I got `datetime` as '`2017-02-25 09:28:42`' in cell 'A1' of Excel.

How do I find if datetime is less than 24 hours and output result as "Yes" or "No" in cell 'B1'?

Example: Assuming current time is '`2017-02-25 09:28:42`'

```
-------------------------
2017-02-19 08:28:42 | No
-------------------------
2017-02-24 23:28:42 | Yes
-------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `NOW()-A1` will return the difference in **days** between the datetime in A1 and the current time. So to check if the time is A1 is less than 24 hours (1 day) before the current time, use

```
=IF(NOW()-A1 > 1,"No","Yes")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula in B1:

```
=IF(NOW()-A1 > 1,"No","Yes")
```

check the following for more info:

**Datetime difference:**

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/calculate-the-difference-between-two-times-e1c78778-749b-49a3-b13e-737715505ff6

**Get current datetime (NOW):**

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/insert-the-current-date-and-time-in-a-cell-b5663451-10b0-40ab-9e71-6b0ce5768138

**If cell is greater than:**

https://exceljet.net/formula/if-cell-is-greater-than